# NodeJS render canvas in browser window

Tags: javascript, node.js, canvas

I am using https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas to create a canvas element inside my node.js application, like this:

```
const canvasLibrary = require('canvas');
const canvas = new canvasLibrary(200, 200);
const canvasCtx = canvas.getContext('2d');

// Write "Awesome!"
canvasCtx.font = '30px Impact';
canvasCtx.rotate(0.1);
canvasCtx.fillText('Awesome!', 50, 100);

// Draw line under text
var text = canvasCtx.measureText('Awesome!');
canvasCtx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)';
canvasCtx.beginPath();
canvasCtx.lineTo(50, 102);
canvasCtx.lineTo(50 + text.width, 102);
canvasCtx.stroke();
```

I want to open a new window, which constantly renders the current state of the canvas, like when I'm drawing to a canvas element in a HTML-frontend website. Is this possible with node.js?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible :

- `socket.io` : server and client (needed for realtime)
- `express` : serving the client

**A simple example** (without socket.io) :

Only using express, you can achieve that when a route is accessed with a GET (open the website with a browser, example : **host.com/show** )

```
router.get('/show', function (req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'image/png');
  canvas.pngStream().pipe(res);
});
```

That example is not really efficient since everytime you access the website you are streaming the canvas into a png and piping it into (sending the state of it as) a response, and if a change is performed the route would have to be re-loaded to receive the new status.

If you add a layer of socket.io communications you could even make the canvas editable simultaneously by all the clients (or only some with authorization) and broadcast the changes to all connected clients. (realtime canvas editing)

Hope this helped as a starting point.

---

**EDIT** : #node-canvas related:

- [canvas.pngStream(options)](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas#canvaspngstreamoptions)
- [canvas.jpegStream() and canvas.syncJPEGStream()](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas#canvasjpegstream-and-canvassyncjpegstream)